# Hide the display of a field conditionally

Tags: views, rules

I have the following scenario:

I have many users created from People->Add user

I have a content type (named Project) with the following fields:

--Leaders (Type: Entity Reference to Users)

--Editors  (Type: Entity Reference to Users)

--Price (Type:  Decimal)

--Duration (Type:  Integer)

I want the Price field to be hidden from logged in users belong to Editors field.

**The difficult point here is that one User could be Editor to “Project 1” (a node from content type Project) and Leader to “Project 2 ”.**

I tried some things with the following modules:  Rules, Field formatter conditions, Views Entity rules, but with no results…

Could you please advise me, how to hide the display of a field considering if the logged in user belongs to “Editors” field for each Project?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter Add Project content form using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) and check for **#options** in **Editors** field and if Current User ID exists in #options and then conditionally show/hide **price** field.

You can also check [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module, to see if you get current logged in users details in it. Not sure if it does.

**NOTE:** You can get current logged in user details in [global $user](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/user/7.x) variable.